# Java > Count Null/NA, 0, Blank Values

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I'm looking at 2 JSON Objects. The structure is like this

```
{
 "a": {},
 "b": [],
 "c": {},
 "d": {
   "eStuff": {},
   "fStuff": [],
   "gStuff": [],
   "hStuff": {}
 },
  "i": [],
  "j": {},
  "k": {}
}
```

I then grab JSON Object of d. Then I converted this into map to compare the two out put what is different, the same, and unique on both. However, I need to look at the values that in eStfuff, fStuff, gStuff, hStuff and find the counts of them for. These have nested JSON data.

```
# of NA/Null Values
# of 0 Values
# of Blank Values
```

I can get the null count with the below. However, having trouble getting the 0 and blank values.

```
Map <String, Object> leftFlatMap = FlatMapUtil.flatten(ballPositionalDataLegacyMap);
int nullCount = Comparision.countFrequencies (leftFlatMap, null);
int zeroCount = Comparision.countFrequencies (leftFlatMap, 0);

 public static int countFrequencies(Map <String, Object> list, Object searchValue) {

  int totalCount = 0;
  Collection <Object> values = list.values();
  for (Object v : values) {
     if  (v == searchValue){
     totalCount = totalCount + 1;
   }
  }
  return totalCount;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more detailed about what you are trying to achieve?
more specifically: please add example JSON Objects and the desired output

Comment: I added basic JSON structure @JavaMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your null and value cases, don't really understand how will you test the "blank" one. Give it a try with this code please.

```
    private static int countFrequencies(Map<String, Object> list, Object o) {
    int totalCount = 0;
    Collection<Object> values = list.values();
    for (Object v : values) {
        if (o == null) {
            if (v == null) totalCount++;
        } else {
            if (Objects.nonNull(v) && v.equals(o)) {
                totalCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return totalCount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This got me the null and values (0, 0.0). Let me dive into the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do this?

```
   if  (v != null && v.equals(searchValue)){
     totalCount = totalCount + 1;
   }
```

Comment: I tried that and I get a java.lang.NullPointerException error.

Comment: You can check to make sure both v and searchValue aren't null before calling the equals method, answer edited.

Comment: I didn't get the error. However, no results returned for null or 0 when I run .equals compared to just ==